# How to update a Xamarin forms mobile App?

Tags: android, xamarin, updates

I have a app created in xamarin forms, I already know how to create the APK, the app is to be used internally, i dont want to publish to the appstore, how can the app be update when is available a new version ?

Comment: Use [Hockey App](https://www.hockeyapp.net/) for distribution and updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your resources at hand and requirements, you have a couple of options. These options include, but are certainly not limited to:

- **Visual Studio Mobile Center** ([link](https://mobile.azure.com)): probably the most obvious choice. Out of the box support for Xamarin, and 'just works'. You can set up different groups of users, add analytics and crash reporting, etc. In the future you might be able to take your configuration to its big brother: VSTS. But beware! The product is in preview right now. Preview in Microsoft-land means free for now, but doesn't have to be in the future. While I expect it not to cost much/anything for basic functionality, it is something to be aware of. Not sure on this, but I think you need to invite your users by hand, so you have to know who you want to invite.
- **Google Play Store** ([link](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)): It's kind of a mis-use, but you could of course leverage the Google Play Stores capabilites for Alpha/Beta testing. Also here you have the ability to create groups and have some basic reporting options. In terms of delivering your app you have some nice options here like A/B testing and unlike Mobile Center (again, I didn't verify this) you can setup a link with which people can enroll themselves. Depending on your needs, this might be nice. In terms of costs, this will set you back 25 dollars once. And you could develop and distribute other apps if you'd like.
- **Manual**: send the APK file manually or hosting it on a shared location. I would prefer this least of all. People are not notified of any updates and you don't have any insights apart from something you might have incorporated in your app. Also you don't have any control over who installs or sees the app, etc.

But of course the prefered way would be to do it through the Google Play enterprise program. See [this website](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/work.html). This provides you and your end-users with a private app store basically. Or as they say:

> A managed version of Google Play is used by enterprises and their employees to access a rich ecosystem of work and productivity apps.

You can have private apps, only available for your targeted audience and still leverage the power of the Google Play store. The experience for your end-users will be unified with the regular app store.

I couldn't find a straight answer, but it seems the private apps will also cost just 25 dollars once and is included in the regular Play Store developer license.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options at your hand:

- use Bitrise or Visual Studio Mobile Center (aka HockeyApp) to build and provide a downloadable version of you app
- in addiont to Bitrise or VS Mobile Center you can set up your own store. Take a look at Relution for example
- build locally on your machine and push it to:

  - a fileshare
  - an FTP-site
  - the user by mail.

Comment: With mobile Center,  from what I have gather, when theres a new version available, mobile center doesnt push an the update to the phone, the user has to go to a link and download the new apk.
Right?

Comment: As far as I have read it is now possible to notify the user about a new version of the app.

Comment: Is possible to update a xamarin app using a service like dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

You have a good way to do that : Use [Beta](https://get.fabric.io) this a service provided by Fabric, you can upload your app with different versions and get access to different teams in your company. It's easy to use and quick to manage.

Hope it helps.